# syntax error near unexpected token

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, wildcards

I'm running this command in jenkins, and it's using sh.
However I'm not sure what this error means in my bash script

```
#! /bin/sh
for d in $(ls -d kube/xx/bb/!(abc*|!cdf*)/ | xargs -I {} basename {} ) ;do echo $d; done
```

```
test.sh: command substitution: line 3: syntax error near unexpected
token `(' test.sh: command substitution: line 3:
`ls -d kube/xx/bb/!(abc*|!cdf*)/ | xargs -I {} basename {} )'
```

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).

Comment: Ya, unfortunately i'm running this inside jenkins pipeline and it uses sh

Comment: `$(ls -d kube/xx/bb/* | grep -v ^abc)`  Does that give you what you're after?

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to use an extended globbing pattern in a script running under `/bin/sh`, which is a shell that generally does not understand those sorts of patterns.

Either switch to a shell that know about these patterns, like `bash`, `ksh`, or `zsh` (with the appropriate options set in each shell), or use something that `/bin/sh` would understand, such as `find`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

find kube/xx/bb -prune ! -name 'abc*' ! -name 'cdf*' -type d -exec basename {} \;
```

Or, if you're using GNU `find`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

find kube/xx/bb -prune ! -name 'abc*' ! -name 'cdf*' -type d -printf '%f\n'
```

In both of these examples, I'm assuming that the `!` in front of `cdf*` in the question is a typo.

Note that there is rarely a need to run `xargs` in a pipeline with `find` as `find` has a perfectly usable `-exec` predicate for executing arbitrarily complex commands.

Also, [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

---

A more manual approach:

```
#!/bin/sh

for pathname in kube/xx/bb/*/; do
    [ -d "$pathname" ] || continue

    name=${pathname%/}
    name=${name#kube/xx/bb/}

    case $name in
        abc*|cdf*) continue ;;
    esac

    printf '%s\n' "$name"
done
```

Comment: or maybe https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs instead of the piece of art in that question